How do you change the global shadow colour in Angular Material
Edit: I have created a StackBlitz with a custom theme here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-shadow-demo
I would like to change the shadows across an entire Angular material theme. Please note that this is not the same as changing the shadow under a specific element, e.g. a card, which has been asked elsewhere.
I know that the functionality exists, but I haven't been able to implement it. The original issue and implementation can be seen here:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11343
My issue is that I have a very rudimentary understanding of Sass mixins, so even though I think the answer to my question is presented, it's not done so in a way that I understand.
Towards the bottom of that issue, it says that I can do themed elevations using the following code:
@import '~angular/material/theming';

$myTheme: ...

@mixin my-elevation($zValue) {
  @include mat-theme-elevation($zValue, $myTheme);
}


Could anybody please a slightly more detailed example of how I might make all of the shadows a different colour? And if it helps at all, here's a link to the diff of the elevation.sass file:
https://github.com/benelliott/material2/commit/73bcbd1cfad94077f77324b66712730492f4817a#diff-218a5cec8571848c0a4784fe7b90b2ce5f9eb29c040e9b9dfd1b0f82731d4381

What version of Angular are you using? 14? 16? 18? (Yes, it matters, Angular has changed their theming system a couple times.)

18, with Material 3-based theme

Looks like you are pretty close. I haven't played with angular in some time so this may be incorrect but appears to work in your playground provided.
I was getting undefined from your custom mixins but the larger issue is you were not calling your mixins, only defining them.
Below I consolidated your mixins to a loop redefining all of the shadows that material offers globally.
@mixin custom-theme-elevations() {
  @for $i from 0 through 24 {
    .mat-elevation-z#{$i} {
      @include mat.elevation($i, rgba($custom-shadow-color, $custom-shadow-opacity));
    }
  }
}

@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);
@include mat.core();
// call your mixin here
@include custom-theme-elevations();

here's your sandbox updated. Can see a red shadow on the menu text using mat-elevation-z2
updated stackblitz per comments:

Thank you Caleb, and yeah, that's pretty close, but it's not quite what I was after. There is a way to customise all elevations, including for the existing components. Your solution doesn't cover the default component behaviour, which is what I'm after. I know itt's possible, but it's definitely non-obvious.

oh I gotcha, would have to override all the mat vars for those. Updated stackblitz below. Quite verbose, but could make that into a loop to handle it all in like 6 lines.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-shadow-demo-6xgcov?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fnav-shell%2Fnav-shell.component.html

Ah, I see now that you just changed the values for the shadow variables which isn't really what I was after, but that's OK. Thanks for the effort.

@tsimon What DID you want, if not to change the variables for the shadow colors?

@EliezerBerlin I wanted to set the one shadow value that is then applied to all shadow instances. I did not want to override each individual drop-shadow in every component.
